# Quiero insertar 2 campos de mi formulario en uno en mi DB mysl con php con arreglos

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estoy intentando insertar un array con valores de 2 variables diferentes para juntarlos en un solo campo, mi conexión y miss tablas están bien, tmb ya tengo la tabla para visual los pedidos aquí los dejo mi código y no sé como terminarlo.

```
include "pedidos/conexion.php";
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

if(isset($_POST['insertar'])){
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
    $edificio=$_POST['edificio'];
    $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
    $fruta=$_POST['fruta'];
    $cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
}
$pedidos=array(
        $fruta => $cantidad
);
foreach ($pedidos as $key => $value){
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO Pedidos (Fecha, Nombre, Telefono, Edificio, Departamento,  Pedido)
VALUES('$fecha', '$nombre', '$telefono', '$edificio', '$departamento', '$pedidos')";
if ($obj_conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
}else {
    echo "";
}
mysqli_close($obj_conexion);
?>
?>
```

Comment: No es buena idea tener el detalle de pedido en una columna, deberías crear una tabla aparte.

Comment: Es muy probable que lo que dice @Triby sea cierto y que tengas que repensar tu modelo de datos, separando las tablas adecuadamente. De todos modos no se entiende cuál es el problema. Por ejemplo, tienes un `foreach` dentro del cual no haces nada. Tampoco dices qué es lo que falla, donde falla, qué error da, etc. Todo eso tienes que decirlo cuando planteas una pregunta.